# Estimations in a ordered field?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, estimation, ordered-fields

**My Problem**: I am stuck with a proof strategy on the following:

So i have got an ordered field $ (K,+,*,<)  $ given. I also have

$x,y\in K$

and $0\le y < x$

I have to proof that, for every n $\in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2$ there is:

$ny^{n-1} < \frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y} < nx^{n-1}$

**What i got so far:**

It can be easily proven that
$ny^{n-1} < nx^{n-1}$. It won't help us much, i guess.

We also know that the fraction in the middle is >0 because nominator and denominator will always stay positive (because $0\le y < x$). This might be of some use.

This inequality just doesn't ring a bell. I know i have to estimate the fraction somehow. Also i wonder why the task is to prove it for a specific field, not just for $\mathbb{R}$ (What difference does it make?)

Any light you can shed on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\;x-y>0\;$ , we have that

$$ny^{n-1}<\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}<nx^{n-1}\iff ny^{n-1}(x-y)<x^n-y^n<nx^{n-1}(x-y)$$

and  for example (left inequality):

$$ny^{n-1}(x-y)<x^n-y^n\iff nxy^{n-1}-ny^n<x^n-y^n\iff y^n(1-n)<x^n-nxy^{n-1}$$

But

$$x^n-nxy^{n-1}>x^n-nx^n=x^n(1-n)>y^n(1-n)$$

using what you mention that "can be easily proven", and thus we're done.

Try to do the rightmost inequality in the same way.

Comment: Good proof, though i can't really see how you transformed here... $nxy^{n-1}-ny^n<x^n-y^n\iff y^n(1-n)<x^n-nxy^{n-1}$

Comment: @FalcoWinkler: $$nxy^{-1}-ny^n<x^n-y^n\implies y^n-ny^n<x^n-nxy^{n-1}\stackrel{\text{factor out common multiple)}}\implies y^n(1-n)<x^n-nxy^{n-1}$$ and etc.

Comment: Ah, yes sure. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:** Factor. We get 
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\cdots +y^{n-1}).$$
 On the right, we have $x-y$ times  a total of $n$ terms, each $\ge y^{n-1}$, and each $\le x^{n-1}$. If $n\ge 2$, there are at least $2$ terms on the right, so the inequalities are strict.

Comment: Ok i see what you did there - but to be honest it is not clear to me why this proves our point. Why is it proven, that (x-y)times the sum of n terms that are each $\ge y^{n-1}$, the whole thing is $\ge y^{n-1}$ as well?

Comment: The whole thing is $\ge ny^{n-1}$. Standard properties of inequality, true in all ordered fields.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K^r$ be the real closure of the ordered field $K$. For each integer $n$, the claim

$$0 \leq y < x \implies ny^{n-1} < \frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y} < nx^{n-1} $$

is a first-order statement in the language of ordered fields. Because the theory of real closed fields is complete, this means the inequality is true for the field $K^r$ if and only if it is true for the field $\mathbb{R}$.

And because $K$ is an ordered subfield of $K^r$, if it is true for $K^r$, then it must be true for $K$ as well.

Thus, if you can prove the statement for the real numbers by your favorite means (e.g. calculus?) for all $n \geq 2$, then for each particular $n \geq 2$ we can invoke the logical machinery to conclude it must be true for all ordered fields, and thus we infer it for all $n \geq 2$ for any ordered field.

---

If you don't want to invoke the logical machinery to prove things automatically, you can still use the basic idea: first use calculus to prove it for $\mathbb{R}$, then digging into the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits and stuff, you can often directly translate the calculus proof into pure algebra.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but i think this is not the way i am supposed to solve it, because we had just little of it in our lectures.